# Can I go to Poland from Ukraine with the Netherlands (schengen, Multi, type C) visa from Ukraine for the first time?

Tags: schengen, netherlands, poland, ukraine

I have multivisa issued by the Netherlands, type C. I have never entered any country using this visa. I am Ukrainian and would like to travel from Ukraine to Poland, maybe visit some other countries. However, I may not visit the Netherlands during my trip. I don't want to make any reservations for a hotel in the Netherlands, buy tickets etc, to confuse the officers that I go to the Netherlands as my final point. 
There is an assumption in Ukraine (maybe, it is a myth), that you have to go to the country the visa was issued by, when traveling for the first time using this visa, or, at least visit this country during the trip. I have no biometrical passport, so no visa-free rules currently apply.
Will there be any problems?

Comment: The standard wisdom here is that the best course of action is to follow the itinerary you actually submitted with your visa application (which should, under the rules, include the country that issued the visa).  If you do anything else, there is a risk that the visa will be revoked on the grounds of fraud.  The magnitude of the risk is difficult to assess, but the consequences of a visa revocation can be long lasting, so you should proceed with caution.

Comment: This visa was issued for business negotiations with my Netherland partner (with orange carpet), which I no longer work with. However, the visa was not revoked, as far as I know.

Comment: You asked visa for NL but entering PL. Unless you show that your main destination will be NL it might cause questions and visa cancellation.

Comment: I would call Polland embassy and ask what should you do. As I understand you don't have a passport with biometric data. Maybe consider getting one?

Comment: Good point, but currently lines are long to get it as a lot of people want to travel to EU now for many reasons. Will get it if find out no way to travel to Amsterdam or will still not be sure that can go without it.